# How do I make JIRA notify a Java application about events?

Tags: java, jira, webhooks

What special configuration do I have to do to make JIRA inform a Java application notified about issue changes (events)? 
I followed the instructions mentioned at [JIRA Webhooks](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/webhooks/)

Answer (score 0):

You should expose HTTP endpoint in your Java application, and define in Jira the webhook configuration, for example:

```
Name: "My webhook"
URL: http://www.myremoteapp.com/webhookreceiver
Scope: all issues
Events: all issue events
```

See Jira Webhook documentation [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/webhooks).

Comment: Beware of scaling issues if you have a very large Jira instance.

Answer (score 0):

As I posted in my question, I did follow the instructions on the webhook tutorial. The thing was that I have to check all the issue related checkboxes as well. I thought that I just have to specify *All Issue Events* and thats it... but I have to check all the checkboxes as well.