# JIRA - Send notification to the customer automtically

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am  creating an application in which customer can submit their complaints. Then I would like to create a ticket  in JIRA on behalf of the customer.

I don’t want to make the user as the reporter. I will use a default account to create the ticket ( reporter).

Is there a way I can send email notification to the customer whenever some update happens to the ticket?

Comment: I guess that the Jira is not accessible to the customer?

Comment: Yes. I do not want to create user account for every customer

Comment: The only thing I found that may help is this: [How do I make JIRA notify a Java application about events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791356/how-do-i-make-jira-notify-a-java-application-about-events)

Comment: I saw https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/#api-rest-api-2-issue-issueIdOrKey-notify-post. But I don't know it's a 1 time action or will happen regularly. Plus I think for this to work everybody should be a Jira user

Answer (score 0):

Could you capture some information about the customer (i.e. email address) in one of the issue fields?  Then you could create a workflow action to send an email to the customer at a particular stage in the workflow, as soon as the issue transitions to that stage.

From [Atlassian Community answer page](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Service-Desk-questions/Send-mail-on-transition-status-change-to-external-recipient/qaq-p/656417):

> - Without Addon (only link, content of the ticket is not included):
>
>   - go to System
>   - Create an Event
>   - Select a notification template
>   - Add a post function to the workflow "Fire Event"
>   - go to the Notification scheme and select the event you have just created and     select "Single email address"
> - With Addon:
>
> This Add-On will help you create and automatically send the
>   reports/issues to any email address at any stage of the workflow or in
>   a scheduled time.
>
> https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.midori.jira.plugin.pdfview/server/overview

Answer (score 0):

You can notify Jira customers using our add-on [Raley Email Notifications](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1214045/raley-email-notifications-for-jira-sd?hosting=cloud&tab=overview)
This will work nicely provided that customer's email is stored in Jira custom field.

Vladimir | RaleyApps

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this using the service desk api (https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/service-desk/rest/#api-rest-servicedeskapi-request-post). I am not sure whether we can do it without service desk.
We can put the customer email id in the 'raiseOnbehalfof' field and we can use a default account credentials for the authentication

```
{
"serviceDeskId": "1",
"requestTypeId": "217",
"requestFieldValues": {
"summary": "Request raised via service REST API",
"description": "test."
},
"raiseOnBehalfOf" : "customer@gmail.com"
}
```

More details can be find here https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Jira-service-desk-cloud-create-a-customer-request-via-email/qaq-p/1075791?utm_source=atlcomm&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=accept_as_solution_reminder&utm_content=topic